# What is the best way to configure a Thinkpad's TrackPoint?

Tags: hardware, mouse, thinkpad, input-devices, udev

The previously useful [ThinkWiki pages](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint) appear quite outdated. I am trying to permanently change my TrackPoint sensitivity and speed settings and enable middle mouse button scrolling. I have tried configure-trackpoint in the past, but the settings were not saved permanently (they are lost after restart).

I have tried `gpointing-device-settings`. Using it, I can get middle mouse button scrolling to work, but I cannot change the speed or sensitivity settings of the trackpoint. All methods on the ThinkWiki page that I've tried do not work as directed in Ubuntu 11.04. Can someone explain how to permanently edit the TrackPoint settings so that I can use it correctly?

Answer (score 55):

Unfortunately there seems to be no easy way. What I will describe is how to create a new Upstart job to set the values on boot through the virtual filesystem under /sys.

1. **Find the device path of your trackpoint**

   Run the following in a gnome-terminal (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gnome-terminal`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

   ```
   find /sys/devices/platform/i8042 -name name | xargs grep -Fl TrackPoint | sed 's/\/input\/input[0-9]*\/name$//'
   ```

   In my case this returns `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2` - change to whatever it returns for you in the following steps.
2. **Find values for sensitivity and speed**

   Run the following commands in a gnome-terminal:

   ```
   echo 220 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity
   ```

   for a sensitivity of 220 (this will ask you for your password), and

   ```
   echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed
   ```

   for a speed of 100. Once you found values you are comfortable with, make the change permanent using an Upstart job:
3. **Create a new udev rule**

   Now we need to apply the settings during the system start. Therefore, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/trackpoint.rules`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will ask you for your password). Then paste the 
   following:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="serio", DRIVERS=="psmouse", WAIT_FOR="/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity", ATTR{sensitivity}="220", ATTR{speed}="110"
   ```

   **(Update)** As `WAIT_FOR` is deprecated, on newer systems you can use `DEVPATH` instead:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="serio", DRIVERS=="psmouse", DEVPATH=="/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2", ATTR{sensitivity}="220", ATTR{speed}="110"
   ```

   Save the file and either reboot or run the commands above:

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   sudo udevadm trigger
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed reply. So I did some more digging and tweaking from the ThinkWiki articles last night, and I discovered something else that worked. First two steps should be the same. Instead of an Upstart job, I used udev rules. I created a file by pressing Alt+F2, typing `gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/trackpoint.rules` and pasted the following: 
`SUBSYSTEM=="serio", DRIVERS=="psmouse", WAIT_FOR="/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity", ATTR{sensitivity}="200", ATTR{speed}="150"`
Then reboot.
Is there any reason I should use Upstart vs udev rules?

Comment: IMO the udev approach is the better one, thanks! Edited that into the answer. :-)

Comment: NOTE: use `DEVPATH=="` (two equals), otherwise it wont work.  Cannot edit the post with just one char change, so just left a comment..

Comment: The udev rule doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 16.04. See the later answers for other approaches (e.g. the one from Nguyen Thanh Tung).

Comment: Is there anyway to make it more sensitive? Mine was on 200 and 255 is nowhere near enough....

Answer (score 23):

Here's how I was able to make the Trackpoint more sensitive:

1. Start in the terminal with:

   ```
   $ xinput --list --short
   ```

   You will see something like this:

   ```
   omicron@omicron:~$ xinput --list --short
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint    id=10.  [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ```
2. Find your Trackpoint device. In my case it is id=10.
3. Find the list of properties available to your device:

   ```
   $ xinput --list-props "10"
   ```
4. To change the speed, do:

   ```
   $ xinput --set-prop "10" "libinput Accel Speed" 0.5
   ```

   "10" here is the device ID (Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint  id=10), so put your ID here, and "0.5" is the level of sensitivity. You can experiment with the sensitivity by putting numbers between 0 and 1. The larger the number, the higher the speed.

   I use 0.4 or 0.45
5. IMPORTANT: When the speed is chosen, copy the command to autostart:

   [image: Startup Applications]

If the settings stop working at some point, check the ID or the device's properties again. There may be some changes to your devices table, and the ID may shift.

Comment: Unfortunately I get:
      `property 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`
Not sure how to do that... any suggestions?
(Thinkpad T420, Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: I think you're restricted to the properties shown by `xinput list-props $device_id` (where `device_id`= 10 in the above example).  For example, on my Thinkpad X1c5 running 18.04, I have a property called `libinput Accel Speed` that seems tweakable

Comment: BTW, changing the Trackpoint rubber cap might also help.  Mine was hopelessly hard (to the point my finger was hurting) and after thoroughly wearing it out (within only 18 months, which never happened on many previous ThinkPads) I decided to invest ca $15 in replacements caps (Lenovo part no 4XH0L55146, comes with 10 of those). The outcome is amazing: my Trackpoint has gone from being way too hard to actually being too sensitive.  The setting that works for me now (X1c5 with `TPPS/2 ALPS TrackPoint` on 18.04) is `"libinput Accel Speed" -1.0` (being the min acceleration setting). YMMV of course

Comment: I have thinkpad E480 and Ubuntu 18.04 and `xinput --set-prop "12" "libinput Accel Speed" -0.5` command worked

Comment: The most upvoted answer stopped working after the most recent system update for some reason (Arch/Manjaro). This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: In my case the TrackPoint was too sensitive (ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th). I had to change `libinput Accel Profile Enabled` to `0, 1` (by default it was `1, 0`). The difference is huge.

Answer (score 15):

For my Thinkpad T530, and Ubuntu 15.10. Just use:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/10-trackpoint.rules
```

and then add the following content on, then restart. The setting value will be kept.

```
ACTION=="add",
SUBSYSTEM=="input",
ATTR{name}=="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint",
ATTR{device/sensitivity}="190",
ATTR{device/speed}="180",
ATTR{device/inertia}="6",
ATTR{device/press_to_select}="0"
```

Comment: This works even when the files needed in the other answers (serio1/sensitivity) do not exist

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. :) (ThinkpadT420, Ubuntu18.04).
Just need to play with the settings, a bit tedious having to restart each time, but I can live with that.

Comment: @JamesBB running `udevadm trigger --action add --subsystem all` will make udev apply the rules to all the present devices.

Comment: @CameronNemo - will try that, thanks!
Seems to need `--subsystem-match all`, but I think that's working.

Answer (score 13):

This is based on Vitaly Dubyna's answer, but updated to work for recent (2019) Thinkpads and Xorg versions (thanks to the comments to that answer).

From the command line, enter this command (only the part after the $):

```
$ xinput | grep -i trackpoint
TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint   id=12
```

Note id=12 (may be different on your system).

```
$ xinput --list-props 12
...
libinput Accel Speed (300):     0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (301):     0.000000
...
```

Experiment with the speed setting; negative values allowed. For example,

```
$ xinput --set-prop 12 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.25
```

Once you're satisfied, add the command as a startup application (typically under Start menu > Preferences > Startup applications).

The above setting name is confirmed for Thinkpad models X1c5 (Ubuntu 18.04), E480 (18.04), and E490 (Mint 19.1).

Note: the numbering (id=12) may get shuffled if you have an external keyboard or mouse plugged in. For more robustness, try this:

```
xinput --set-prop $(xinput | perl -ne 'if(/TrackPoint.*id=(\d+)/) { print $1; }') 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.25
```

Answer (score 4):

@vitaly-dubyna has the right answer. On debian his method works flawlessly.
To make your life easier, put a file `.xsessionrc` in your home directory with all the settings so that it will be loaded after each restart.

make a new file use `vim`, `pico`, `gedit` --

```
vim .xsessionrc
```

then stick this inside

```
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 7 6 4 5
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.4
```

where the first 4 lines is to setup vertical and horizontal scrolling with trackpoint and the last line is to control the speed / and sensitivity.

Note that because the device ID can change depending on whether some input devices are enabled / disabled in BIOS, it is preferable to use the device name in quotes. For most thinkpads `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint` is the reference.

---

**EDIT:**Nov 2015

```
#get the device ID for the trackpad. We know it contains the string "TPPS"
ibm_trackpad_id=$(xinput | grep 'TPPS' | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -f1)
echo $ibm_trackpad_id > ~/temp/ibm_trackpad_id

#set desired params for trackpoint
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 7 6 5 4
xinput set-prop $ibm_trackpad_id "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.15

# get wireless mouse device ID 
logitech_mouse_id=$(xinput | grep "Logitech" | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -f1)
echo $logitech_mouse_id > ~/temp/logitech_mouse_id

# this is device dependent. Map the buttons on your mouse the functionality you want. 
xinput set-button-map $logitech_mouse_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

# set props for external mouse
xinput set-prop $logitech_mouse_id "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.7
xinput set-prop $logitech_mouse_id "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" 2
xinput set-prop $logitech_mouse_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop $logitech_mouse_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 7 6 5 4
xinput set-prop $logitech_mouse_id "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8
```

Comment: Your `"Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes"` setting uses natural scrolling horizontally, normal scrolling vertically. I guess most want all-natural scrolling (use `7 6 5 4`) or all-normal scrolling (use `6 7 4 5`).

Comment: As of Ubuntu 17.10, the `evdev` driver that this solution relies on is no longer installed by default. You can still install it with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev` or use the now-default `libinput` driver instead. In which case, the [answer by @htorque](https://askubuntu.com/a/37841) is the way to configure speed and sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Thinkpad Yoga 4th Gen, the following permanently changes the trackpoint settings (taken from [post](https://silvae86.github.io/2019/05/17/tuning-ibm-lenovo-trackpoint/)).

**Step 0**. Figure out the name of the device (as htorque [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/37841/41363)):

`find /sys/devices/platform/i8042 -name name | xargs grep -Fl TrackPoint | sed 's/\/input\/input[0-9]*\/name$//'`

For me it returns `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1` (without `serio2`).

Now I quote a slightly modified original [post](https://silvae86.github.io/2019/05/17/tuning-ibm-lenovo-trackpoint/):

> **Step 1**. Install sysfsutils:
>
> `sudo apt-get install sysfsutils`
>
> **Step 2**. Edit the `/etc/sysfs.conf`. Add the following lines at the end.
>
> ```
> devices/platform/i8042/serio1/sensitivity = 215
> devices/platform/i8042/serio1/rate = 280
> devices/platform/i8042/serio1/speed = 150
> devices/platform/i8042/serio1/inertia = 1
> ```
>
> Play with the values until you find the ones you like. Run `sudo service sysfsutils restart` to apply the changes.

Note that those settings persist over restart.

Comment: Thanks so much! I setup this solution many years ago (Ubuntu 11.10?) and then recently reset it accidentally during an upgrade. I had no idea how to recreate it until I found your answer. Works perfectly, except I do need the `/serio1/serio2` device path, but your Step 0 command told me that anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

### Configure `libinput` options via xorg.conf.d and udev

As of Ubuntu 17.10, the `libinput` driver is now the standard.

Some of its options can be configured via the X.org mechanism, but speed and sensitivity need to be configured with udev rules to put in kernel driver parameters. (See the [answer by @htorque](https://askubuntu.com/a/37841) for that.)

For configuring the other options, create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-trackpoint-tweaks.conf` (or similarly named). The file should have this content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "Trackpoint tweaks"
    MatchProduct       "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath    "/dev/input/event*"

    # The default driver now, so optional to put in this line. 
    # But does not hurt mentioning where the options will go.
    Driver             "libinput"

    Option             "NaturalScrolling"      "true"
EndSection
```

To see the effect, you have to restart X of course. For the list of the other available X.org options, see [man(4) libinput](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4).

For a list of the corresponding (but differently named) xinput properties, see `xinput --list-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"` or again [man(4) libinput](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4). You can use these to test out effects immediately with `xinput --set-prop […]` commands, without having to restart X every time. And then use the equivalents in the `52-trackpoint-tweaks.conf` file to make the changes permanent, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Ubuntu 15.04** or later (Which will have SystemD installed instead of Upstart), then there is a method posted here which you can use:

https://askubuntu.com/a/611076/253579

Answer (score 0):

I have a thinkpad and got everything setup as desired through an application called Pointing Devices, which is just a bit more advanced mouse settings dialog.

I don't recall how many options there were for sensitivity, but unlike the built-in mouse settings screen, this one regognized the trackpoint and trackpad independently and allowed for greater control like setting the scroll button (was button 2 in my configuration) and enabling palm detection sensitivity.

Comment: There are no options for sensitivity or speed with gpointing-device-settings.

Answer (score 0):

### Configure `evdev` options via xorg.conf.d (DEPRECATED)

The `evdev` driver was the default driver for the trackpoint in earlier versions of Ubuntu, but as of Ubuntu 17.10, the approach below is deprecated and does not work out of the box anymore. This is because the `evdev` driver which is not installed by default anymore as the `libinput` driver is the standard now – see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/590926) for configuring that.

If you want, you can still use the `evdev` solution below after installing the driver with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev` ([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man4/evdev.4.html)).

Everything can be configured nicely in an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-trackpoint-tweaks.conf` file (or similarly named – on Ubuntu, you have to create directory and file, but the mechanism works; maybe one of the directory names is `x11` instead of `X11` in some versions).

The file should have this content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Trackpoint tweaks"
    MatchProduct       "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath    "/dev/input/event*"

    # Specify the driver, as else Ubuntu 17.10 will use libinput.
    Driver             "evdev"

    # Configure wheel emulation, using middle button and "natural scrolling".
    Option             "EmulateWheel"            "on"
    Option             "EmulateWheelButton"      "2"
    Option             "EmulateWheelTimeout"     "200"
    Option             "EmulateWheelInertia"     "7"
    Option             "XAxisMapping"            "7 6"
    Option             "YAxisMapping"            "5 4"

    # Set up an acceleration config ("mostly linear" profile, factor 5.5).
    Option             "AccelerationProfile"     "3"
    Option             "AccelerationNumerator"   "55"
    Option             "AccelerationDenominator" "10"
    Option             "ConstantDeceleration"    "3"
EndSection
```

To see the effect, you have to restart X of course. To play with these settings while X is running, use `xinput`, but note that option names are different there.

As pointed out by @Vitaly Dubyna, "Constant Deceleration" can be used to control sensitivity – it scales down all movements with that factor, so value "3" makes all movements 3 times slower compared to default "1".

Option documentation:

- [evdev driver manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/evdev.4.html) (for EmulateWheel options)
- [X.org pointer acceleration manual](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/)
- [more on mouse acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

On `Lubuntu 19.10` for a `X201 Thinkpad` my red trackpoint was too sensitive.

I opened the `Preferences -> LXQt settings -> Keyboard and Mouse`

I scrolled down the left pane to `Mouse and Touchpad`

I selected the device `TTPS/2 IBM TrackPoint`

I changed the `Acceleration speed` to -1,00 (minus one)