# Disabling trackpoint in HP Elitebook 8730w?

Tags: 11.04, trackpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to configure a Thinkpad's TrackPoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37824/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-a-thinkpads-trackpoint)

The trackpoint is kinda broken  ... on slightest touch it yanks down the mouse pointer to the bottom of the screen. With enough fingering I can make it free again. gpointing-device-settings does not show any config option for the trackpoint. Please help ...

Comment: This should get you started  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection .

Comment: Instead of disabling it (I'd check the BIOS of your notebook for that), try to configure it like described in above link. You maybe need to tweak it a bit as that's for a Lenovo TrackPoint. Also, you can just try to change sensitivity and acceleration in the mouse settings (not gpoint-device-settings).