# Ubuntu won't save my settings for thinkpad trackpoint

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad, udev, trackpoint

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Thinkpad X200. To configure the trackpoint, I use ["configure TrackPoint"](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint#configure-trackpoint). Unfortunately I can't make Ubuntu saving my settings (concerning the sensitivity etc.). Whenever I reboot the computer, it's set to generic settings again.

I already tried htorque's answer to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/37841) and created a new udev-rule for the trackpoint-settings but it didn't helped.

So, how can I make theses settings permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a working solution:

**1. Find the device path of your trackpoint**

Run the following in a gnome-terminal (can be opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
find /sys/devices/platform/i8042 -name name | xargs grep -Fl TrackPoint | sed 's/\/input\/input[0-9]*\/name$//'
```

It will return something like

```
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2
```

change to whatever it returns for you in the following step.

**2. Create a new upstart-job**

Still in the terminal type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/init/trackpoint.conf
```

A text editor will pop up. Paste the following code in it:

```
description "Trackpoint-Settings"
env TPDIR=/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2
start on virtual-filesystems
script
  while [ ! -f $TPDIR/sensitivity ]; do
        sleep 2
  done
  echo -n 200 > $TPDIR/sensitivity
  echo -n 150 > $TPDIR/speed
  echo -n 1 > $TPDIR/press_to_select
end script
```

Don' forget to edit the second line if needed (see step 1).

You can edit the numbers in line eight and nine (representing *sensitivity* and *speed*) to whatever you prefer. Both can be set in a range from 0 to 255. Leaving them at 200 and 150 works good for me.

**Save** and **exit**.

That's it.

Comment: To anyone who happens on this from a later version of ubuntu which is using systemd instead of upstart, there is info here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/596085/increase-trackpoint-sensititvity-with-systemd-ubuntu-15-04-or-later

Again, be sure to adjust the device path accordingly.