# Is there a way to enable tap to click for the Thinkpad trackpoint using systemd in 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, thinkpad, trackpoint

Is there a way to enable tap to click for the Thinkpad trackpoint using systemd in 15.04? I know sensitivity can be adjusted, but I have not seen a way to enable tap to click. There's instructions here on how to adjust sensitivity under systemd:

[Increase Trackpoint Sensititvity with SystemD (Ubuntu 15.04 or later)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596085/increase-trackpoint-sensititvity-with-systemd-ubuntu-15-04-or-later/612412#612412)

I've not found out how to enable tap to click though

Comment: Closers, this is a bug?

Comment: me too. toshiba satellite notebook and cannot figure out how to enable tap to click in 14.04 and 15.04

Answer (score 0):

As per http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint#Configuration_using_sysfs, on my X200 (which has no touchpad) with Ubuntu 16.04, I used `sudu -i` to become superuser, then `echo -n 1 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/press_to_select` to turn it on and now it works, though it's a little more sensitive than I might like so it'll take some getting used to. Thinkpads with a touchpad will have a slightly different path in the command, see the link. Also in the link is info on making the change permanent, if desired.

Edit: Found the related https://askubuntu.com/a/761504/392539, which happens to include a possibly simpler way to make this permanent (along with other trackpoint settings), but haven't tried it myself.