# kubuntu 15.04 trackpoint sensitivity

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5, trackpoint

I'm running the latest kubuntu with plasma 5 on a t440s laptop. The trackpoint is very slow and there's no option to increase the sensitivity under the system input settings. The same laptop is running elementary os freya and I can adjust this via xinput. On kubuntu changing the xinput values has no effect.

Any idea how I can adjust this?

Comment: Well, it's working now with xinput. Apparently I need to set values different than the ones I have on elementary OS.

Answer (score 4):

The change the sensitivity (and speed, etc.) permanently, you can create an udev rule.

E.g. create a file `10-trackpoint.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` with the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="serio", DRIVERS=="psmouse", WAIT_FOR="/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity", ATTR{sensitivity}="220",  ATTR{speed}="190", ATTR{inertia}="6", ATTR{press_to_select}="0"
```

This method was tested on Ubuntu 14.04 up to 15.04.

For further explanations check on the [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrackPoint) and [Thinkwiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint) and look for "sensitivity".

**Update for Ubuntu 15.10**

The above rule does not trigger properly on Ubuntu 15.10. Instead use:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTR{name}=="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint", ATTR{device/sensitivity}="220", ATTR{device/speed}="190", ATTR{device/inertia}="6", ATTR{device/press_to_select}="0"
```