# How to make Trackpoint Speed permanent with systemd-tmpfiles? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, trackpoint

I followed the instructions from the question "[Increase Trackpoint Sensitivity with SystemD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596085/increase-trackpoint-sensititvity-with-systemd-ubuntu-15-04-or-later/878578#878578)".

So far everything works almost fine. Though the settings are not kept and I need to perform `sudo systemd-tmpfiles --prefix=/sys --create` after every restart.

How can I make this setting permanent?

It seems that Ubuntu does not create the tmpfiles at startup?!