# Thinkpad - Trackpoint configuration on 18.10+?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, 18.10, trackpoint

I have a new Lenovo x280 and am trying to configure the trackpoint following tips [that worked on older machines/installs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596085/increase-trackpoint-sensititvity-with-systemd-ubuntu-15-04-or-later).

However, the command:

```
find /sys/devices/platform/i8042 -name name | xargs grep -Fl TrackPoint | sed 's/\/input\/input[0-9]*\/name$//'
```

returns nothing, the only device I can find is the keyboard.

Has something changed in 18.10 or do I need to do something else to configure the trackpoint properly?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 19.10 on my T480. I was able to find the files in `/sys/devices/rmi4-00/rmi4-00.fn03/serio2`.