# Lenovo T480 jumpy trackpoint with 16.04

Tags: drivers, mouse, lenovo, trackpoint

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 desktop version on my T480. I'm generally happy with the performance and nice keyboard but trackpoint is quite jumpy and wiggles a little when I'm bringing track point to desired place.

This happened when I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on T470P in the past. I wonder this is hardware issue or driver issue and can be fixed.

https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201801-26058/
https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201605-22282/

When I see mouse driver for T460
Aquantia Corp. TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint is used and I wonder this has something to do with the issue.

Some digging around got me to this setting but "accel-profile" not present in my T480

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'adaptive'

I wonder if there are any other users experiencing this.

Thanks

Takeshi

Comment: The same issue as you describe it is happening on my T470 and fresh installation of 18.04

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a problem specific to Ubuntu. I had the same issue on my T480 running Manjaro / Cinnamon. Libinput version is 1.11.0-1.

I represent my solution here. It should be applicable to Ubuntu as well with minor modifications.

**Disable trackpoint acceleration:**

Write new Xorg configuration file (i.e. /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-trackpoint.conf):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Trackpoint"
        MatchProduct "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Accel Speed" "0"
        Option "Accel Profile" "flat"
EndSection
```

**Calibrate trackpoint range:**

Write new hwdb adjustment file (i.e. /etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-trackpoint.hwdb):

```
evdev:name:TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint*
    LIBINPUT_ATTR_TRACKPOINT_RANGE=50
```

**Restart computer**

**Adjust sensitivity/speed:**

```
echo 97 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed
echo 255 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity
```

Comment: What does `LIBINPUT_ATTR_TRACKPOINT_RANGE` mean?

Comment: If I recall correctly it adjusts the granularity of the trackpoint. Too low value removes the finesse from trackpoint sensitivity while too large value may cause the mouse cursor move when not intended.

Comment: This is awesome, the TrackPoint feels super smooth now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used the following to make this persistent across reboots: https://askubuntu.com/a/761504/161212