# Thinkpad trackpoint scrolling speed

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

How can one change trackpoint scrolling speed? It's way to slow (T480s + Ubuntu 18.04). Mouse speed setting seems working fine and mouse speed is suitable but it doesn't affect scrolling speed at all. Also for some reason i don't have xinput speed and sensitivity params (to try [What is the best way to configure a Thinkpad's TrackPoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37824/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-a-thinkpads-trackpoint/511281) solutions).

[image]
`/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

`/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1$ xinput --list-props 13
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (287):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (288):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (305): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (306): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (298):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (299): 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (300): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (307):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (308):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (309):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (301): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (302): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (264): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (265):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (266):    0, 0
    Device Node (267):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (268):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (303):   
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (304):   1`

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint" "libinput Accel Speed" 2
```

and see if it increased the speed. You could put this setting on your ~/.xinitrc so that it'll be saved for your user.

Comment: Seems like 1 is max value. The range is from -1 to 1. Anyway it doesn't affect scrolling speed, only cursor speed.