# How do I configure the Trackpoint on my Lenovo running Ubuntu 21.04 and stay sane?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, configuration, thinkpad

Is there a **easy**(er) **way** to **configure a Trackpoint** on a **Lenovo** Laptop (I have a E495) than to learn everything about libinput and xinput? (which one to use? xinput complains about Wayland? Do I need to know about the x-server now too?) I just want to change the speed settings of the Trackpad, and it feels like studying for a CS Bachelors Degree? It's just the f'ing mouse! This is way more complicated than to setup TLP for better energy management on my Thinkpad. That took ages too, at least it's a special use case, but something as basic as the pointing device?!

Can anyone point me to a tutorial that isn't more complicated than editing a config file or basic command usage in the terminal? Maybe something that is a little more structured than what I already look at? Step-by-Step Guide? Everything I linked to seems very outdated...

And feel free to tell me that there is a very obvious and easy to find option in the GUI everyone knows about, so I can feel really stupid! ;-p

Any advice is appreciated!

Thx Jan

What I have read:

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/tools.html#libinput-list-devices

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244883

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mouse_acceleration#Mouse_acceleration_with_libinput

https://silvae86.github.io/2019/05/17/tuning-ibm-lenovo-trackpoint/

[What is the best way to configure a Thinkpad's TrackPoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37824/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-a-thinkpads-trackpoint)

https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/5rcwlq/heres_how_to_get_the_perfect_trackpoint/

https://baach.de/Members/jhb/fixing-the-trackpoint-on-ubuntu

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/noromanba/11261595/raw/478cf4c4d9b63f1e59364a6f427ffccd63db5e1e/thinkpad-trackpoint-speed.mkd

Comment: If you want to change your trackpoint sens without affecting the mouse sens, you can use a very small shell script: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604626/how-to-set-trackpoint-sensitivity/753976#753976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the settings (Gear icon), and select "Mouse and Touchpad" from the list. Under "Mouse", change the "Mouse Speed" and the trackpoint speed changes too.