# Change thumbstick's sensitivity

Tags: mouse

I have a laptop from HP with that little knob in the middle of the keyboard with which you can control the mouse pointer. [Image of that thumbstick-knob-thingy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj4Ht.jpg)
On Windows the pointer raced across the screen when I even touched this thumbstick but since I replaced Windows with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it moves painfully slow, even on full tilt of the thumbstick.
I have no idea on how to set its sensitivity as there's only mouse and touchpad settings but none for this thumbstick.
I would prefer terminal-based solutions so I can also use them on my second laptop with Linux Mint (graphical solutions are still fine and appreciated).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure the Trackpoint on my Lenovo running Ubuntu 21.04 and stay sane?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338122/how-do-i-configure-the-trackpoint-on-my-lenovo-running-ubuntu-21-04-and-stay-san)

Comment: @ubfan1 The solution to [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338122/how-do-i-configure-the-trackpoint-on-my-lenovo-running-ubuntu-21-04-and-stay-san) question changes how the mouse behaves but the mouse is totally fine. I want to somehow adjust the thumbstick seperately without making the cursor jump into one corner of the screen by just touching the mouse (the thumbstick seems to count as a mouse and I have the mouse speed on maximum because my mouse is really slow but the thumbstick is slower) Is there any extra driver I can get to seperately set the thumbstick's sensitivity?